# How to actively update a JList in Java

Tags: java, swing

I'm working on a project where one of the parameters is that either a table or a list needs to display multiple names it's reading from a text file. Im using Swing and JList for this, but I'm having a lot of trouble actually updating the list with the new information.

```
public void selectTable(ArrayList<String> select) {
    DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
    model.addElement(select);
    selectList = new JList(model);
    selectList.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(690, 230));   
}
```

I keep reading that you're supposed to use the Default List Model to update it, but everytime I try theres no change on the GUI side of things, the JList stays blank. Looking through the debugger, the array list I have goes into the add element method, but nothing changes

Answer (score 5):

Edit:

In JDK 11 you can create a `DefaultListModel` and then add the `ArrayList` to the model using the `addAll(...)` method of the `DefaultListModel`:

```
    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
    items.add("one");
    items.add("two");

    DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
    model.addAll( items );

    JList<String> list = new JList<>(model);
```

---

Original answer (when I was using JDK8):

You can't add an `ArrayList` to the `DefaultListModel`.

You need to add each item of the `ArrayList` to the `DefaultListModel` separately.

So you need to iterate through the `ArrayList` and add each item in the `ArrayList` to the model by using the `addElement(...)` method.

Also, you don't show in your code where you add the `JList` to a `JScrollPane` and then add the `JScrollPane` to the frame.

Comment: Should look something like:
JList jlist = new JList(model);
JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(jlist);
frame.add(scrollPane1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
And then you can edit your frame properties to change size.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I didn't think to add it to the Scroll Pane, but I have to add them both to a separate panel since this is part of a bigger project. But I'm not doing very well because now I cannot see my JList at all.

Comment: Is there a better way to format comments? I apologize, I'm new here and I'm very panicked at the moment.

Comment: @MilesJordan don't post code in a comment (please delete the code). Code should be included with the question so it can be properly format and visible to everybody who reads the question. I suggest you first start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for working examples. Then once you understand the basics you apply the knowledge to your real program. If you need more help, then post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Do you find it strange, Oracle updating the Swing library when they don't even seem like they support it much anymore, seemingly favoring the newer library, JavaFX? 1+

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  - a bit strange, but I always wondered why Collections were not supported. Better late than never. Just checked the DefaultComboBoxModel and it has also been updated to include the `addAll(...)` method. Guess it pays to glance at the API every now and then.